# ImageView - null object reference

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I'm building a `reyclerView` that loads images into the titleChild. I uploaded `test_image` into res/drawable but I keep seeing null object reference at

```
titleChildViewHolder.option1.setImageResource(R.drawable.test_image);
titleChildViewHolder.option2.setImageResource(R.drawable.test_image);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w54gJ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In your xml file where you define the ImageView I suggest you to set the src of the imageview to test_image.

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/option1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/test_image" />
```

Also check that the file is present in your res/drawable which many a times results in NPE.